# Abstract class as many to many key in django models

Tags: python, django, abstract-class

I was thinking of creating something like a QoS in django. My first thought was to create an abstract class of a service and then create a concrete class of every actual service my stystem would provide. Then one model class would be the the container QoSPlan that would have a many to many key to each concrete class I made so I can create distinct QoSPlans that I could e.g grant to users.

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class DiskQoutaService(models.Model):
    max_size = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Max size in Gb"

class AppsAllowed(models.Model):
    apps = models.CharField(max_length=100):
```

and the QoSPlan

```
class QoSPlan(models.Model):
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)
```

Is this possible with django? Is there a way to bypass this behaviour. I know it's different but I saw this happening in java and jpa entities and was wondering if it can be done in python. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have foreign keys on an abstract model for the very obvious reason that there's no underlying table in the database - remember that django's model classes are mapping to db tables.

"Inheritance" in a relational database can be implemented in two ways: shared table with views (or, in Django, shared model and Proxy models), and multiple tables with one to one relationship (concrete inheritance in Django). Both solutions have their pros and cons : multi-table requires joins and/or unions, shared table means a huge table with lot of unused fields and possible name clashes between subclasses.

NB: if you choose the multi-tables scheme, you'll certainly benefit from [django-polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic)

If you want to take the

Comment: So in your personal opinion which is the best way to achieve that. Using django-polymorphic?using type? Trying to put common methods in every child class?